# How to add text layer on images in the CMS editor?

Tags: image

If I add an image to a cms page, Is it possible to add a layer of text to sit on the the image?  For example,

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

This question is off-topic, IMO, but there's no clear option for me to flag it. So, here's my take on it.

This is really a CSS question. But in the context of Magento, here's how to solve. First, you would use inline CSS on the elements by editing the HTML from the tinyMCE content editor:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <img src="//url.to/your/image.png" width="500" height="320" />
    <p style="position:absolute; top:60%; left:0; background-color:#000; color:#fff">
        A Movie in the Park: Kung Fu Panda
    </p>
</div>
```

Otherwise, you could edit the stylesheet for the current theme to contain these styles inside of defined rules.